# Next.js routing: pushing a new route from a slug page doesn't route properly

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

Let's say I have 2 routes: `/video` and `/products/[id]`, so my `pages` folder contains `video.js` and `products/[id].js`. When I use `router.push` or `Link` to navigate to `/video` from `/products/[id]`, the URL gets updated to `/products/video`. Obviously this is not the correct behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you share the code related to the behaviour you described? Also, I assume `products[id].js` is a typo, and you meant `products/[id].js`?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes it's a typo, I updated the original question; I also wrote /video/products instead of /products/video. Regarding the code you wanted to see, it really is just a normal router.push('video) or Link href='video >..</Link>

Comment: However simple it may be, it's always good to provide the code related to the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the path to the video page as `/video` rather than just `video`. Otherwise it'll route in relation to the current path you're on - which from your products page is `/products`.

```js
router.push('/video')
```

```js
<Link href="/video">...</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you didnt name your files properly.

To get /video, you just have video.js as your page.

To get /products/[id] page, you need to have /products/[id].js file

You DONT name it as products[id].js. It's just [id].js.

So put your [id].js file inside your /products folder.

And put your video.js file inside your pages folder. eg /pages/video.js goes to /video route

And /pages/products/[id].js will go to /products/id.

Summary: Your pages folder should have video.js file, and create folder products, and put [id].js file in your products folder.

Comment: You are right on these, I had typos in my original question and also updated the resulting url to /products/video instead of /video/products